# aligning divs vertically without any space between them

Tags: html, css

```html
<div style="border:8px solid purple;height:500px;position:relative;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;bottom:0;width:100%;position:absolute;border:5px solid black;">
    <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid red;width:100%;position:relative;">
      TEXT INSIDE RED BORDER DIV
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;border:4px solid yellow;height:20px;width:100%;position:relative;transform:translateY(50%);">
      TEXT INSIDE YELLOW BORDER DIV
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;border:4px solid blue;height:50px;width:100%;">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't want any space between div that has "TEXT INSIDE RED BORDER DIV" text inside and div that has "TEXT INSIDE YELLOW BORDER DIV" inside. But there is a space between them. It appears that `transform:translateY(50%);` doing this.

Why doesn't red div move downwards automatically and as a result cause space between yellow div?

Comment: reduce the line height of `element`?

Answer (score 1):

remove `transform: translateY(50%);` from your yellow bordered div, it will removes the space

```html
<div style="border:8px solid purple;height:500px;position:relative;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;bottom:0;width:100%;position:absolute;border:5px solid black;">
    <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid red;width:100%;position:relative;">
      TEXT INSIDE RED BORDER DIV
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;border:4px solid yellow;height:20px;width:100%;position:relative;">
      TEXT INSIDE YELLOW BORDER DIV
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;border:4px solid blue;height:50px;width:100%;">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The pen linked isn't even the same code, sorry but we can't help a lot without this.

But, maybe this will resolve your problems, in CSS the inline-block properties put element one after others but let a space due to the font size.

If you set the font size to all your element to : 0 and re-setting the correct font size inside the div the space will go away (normally)

Comment: i deleted the pen link!